# What type is more reasonable to use for document numbers

Tags: java, c++, types, storing-data, storing-information

For example we have a class person, who has a passport number field. Which type is better to use. In case it is a number, which is significantly big, but we do not need to perform any calculations with it, so we probably can use it with a string? And why?

Comment: My opinion: go with `String`...

Comment: @brso05 Can you explain why?

Comment: passport number in some countries contains characters, so there is no question "what type", you have the only type - string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1090065/4028085

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1090100/4028085

Comment: As long as it is not the primary key, you should use a string, because passport numbers might contain non digit characters. And as it is a *significant* value that can change over the time (I change my passport and get a new number every 5 or 10 years), it would be a poor candidate for a primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A passport number is an identifier, not a number. I don't know if it's actually done, but consider cases with leading zeroes, or if we run out of numbers and start prefixing with letters, etc. You should absolutely use a non-numeric type such as string.

Comment: I second that. I used to work on a project that used `Long` for article numbers because they were just numbers at that time. Then the inevitable happened: a customer started to use alpha numeric article "numbers". All the code had to be adapted to use `String` instead of `Long` - you can imagine what that meant.